# RHEL9, OpenJDK 11, FIPS - issues with PBES2 ciphers

Tags: java, openssl, java-11, fips, rhel9

I've read through several topics related to this issue but none so far have helped.

We're running RHEL9 with OpenJDK 11.0.22 and OpenSSL 3.0.7, with FIPS mode enabled (disabling FIPS is not an option). We have an SSL cert, private key, and intermediate/root certs which I'm attempting to use as a keystore for our Java apps. I can combine them into a PKCS12 file, which works fine, but that's where the problems begin -

Java can't read the PKCS12 file because OpenSSL is using FIPS-compliant PBES2 ciphers -

`java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: PBES2 AlgorithmParameters not available`

Many threads on this issue.

Converting the PKCS12 file into a JKS file fails for the same reason - keytool has trouble with the PBES2 ciphers. Running OpenSSL with the legacy provider to generate the PKCS12 file doesn't work as the legacy provider is blocked by FIPS.

According to the java.security file on the server in question, PBES2 ciphers are available and are the defaults (i.e. PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256 and HmacPBESHA256). According to the documentation I've found, OpenJDK 11.0.22 should support PBES2.

Why is our OpenJDK install struggling with this when everything seems to imply that PBES2 support should exist?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: To my knowledge recent versions of Java support `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256` as alorithm to decrypt/read PKCS#12 files. The only other supported algorithm is the old legacy algo that bases on SHA1 and 3DES. If both are not available in FIPS mode, the PKCS#12 files won't be loadable.

Comment: Java supports PBES2 since the middle of 8 up; there were bugs in the handling of PBES2 _using SHA2_ (or more exactly not using SHA1) but those were fixed in 11.0.12 up. All builds I use of 11.0.12 or higher (Oracle, Adoptium/Temurin, IBM/Semeru) can read an OpenSSL3-created pkcs12. I assume you are using a RedHat package/build, and I don't know what they do to integrate it with their systemwide policy; that may have broken something. If your _application_ doesn't need to be FIPS you could use a non-RH Java. ...

Comment: ... Or in any case you could try `openssl pkcs12 -export -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES` -- that should work with OpenSSL-under-FIPS _and_ is not PBES2. PS: even if you could create JKS, it would _never_ satisfy FIPS; it uses a never-Approved or even standardized cipher that was _designed_ to be breakable.

Comment: Turns out FIPS is disabling the SunJCE provider, which contains all of the PBE and PBES2 ciphers. None of the other Java security providers available under FIPS offer these ciphers, at least on our systems, so that seems to be what's killing Java's ability to handle the PKCS12 files. We'll probably try the NSS approach and see how that goes. Thanks for the response.